# ThreeJs OBJLoader + MTLLoader : materials load but don't show

Tags: typescript, three.js

Using OBJLoader and MTLLoader, I'm trying to load a low-poly car model that I downloaded from the internet into my Three.JS scene. This model doesn't even have textures. However, although I do see the model, I don't see the materials on it (right car on the screenshot). I opened the `.obj` file in Blender, and I do see the low-poly car's color there in Cycles rendering.

The materials *are* loaded, since when I `console.log` the value returned by `ObjMtlLoader.load` (see code below), I can see the material names, and the color values correspond to what is present in the MTL file.

To be honest, I'm not totally sure it's a problem with `OBJLoader` or `MTLLoader`, since I tried the `ColladaLoader` (left car on the screenshot), and it does not show materials either, apart from the wheels.

I would like to know if, given this limited context, you had any clues as to what could be the cause. I would research this problem more in-depth, but I already work, say, 10 hours a day, including week-ends. I guess if nothing works, I'll just try to manually create the materials.

Here is an excerpt of code:

```
// obj-mtl-loader.ts

export class ObjMtlLoader {

    private objLoader: THREE.OBJLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    private mtlLoader: THREE.MTLLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();

    constructor(basePath?: string) {
        if (basePath) {
            this.objLoader.setPath(basePath);
            this.mtlLoader.setPath(basePath);
        }
    }

    public load(objFile: string, mtlFile: string): Promise<THREE.Group> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.mtlLoader.load(
                mtlFile,
                (materialCreator) => {
                    materialCreator.preload();
                    this.objLoader.setMaterials(materialCreator);
                    this.objLoader.load(
                        objFile,
                        (model) => {
                            resolve(model);
                        },
                        () => {},
                        (reason) => reject(reason)
                    );
                },
                () => {},
                (reason) => reject(reason)
            );
        });
    }

}
```

Here is an example usage:

```
// renderer.ts
    new ObjMtlLoader().load(
        '/assets/racing/car_model/Low-Poly-Racing-Car.obj',
        '/assets/racing/car_model/Low-Poly-Racing-Car.mtl'
    ).then((car) => {
        this.SCENE.add(car);
    });
```

And here is a screenshot:

[image: Demo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, ThreeJS (or maybe the version of ThreeJS that I have) doesn't like multimaterials. When I split my meshes by material in Blender, everything looks normal.